# How to implement a Fredkin gate using Toffoli and CNOTs?

Tags: quantum-gate, circuit-construction

Inspired by a question [Toffoli using Fredkin](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/9339/toffoli-using-fredkin), I tried to do "inverse" task, i.e. to implement Fredkin gate (or controlled swap). In the end I implemented it with three Toffoli gates.

Firstly, I started with swap gate without control qubit which is implemented with CNOTs followingly:

[image: Swap gate]

Then I realized that I need control qubit, or in other words that I have to control each CNOT gate. As controlled CNOT is Toffoli gate (CCNOT gate), I came to this circuit

[image: Fredking gate]

As matrix representation of Toffoli gate controlled by qubits $|q_0\rangle$ and $|q_1\rangle$ is
\begin{equation}
CCNOT_{01} =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

matrix of Toffoli gate controlled by qubits $|q_0\rangle$ and $|q_2\rangle$ is
\begin{equation}
CCNOT_{02} =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

and finnaly, matrix of Fredking gate is
\begin{equation}
F =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

Since $F=CCNOT_{01} CCNOT_{02} CCNOT_{01}$, the circuit is designed corectly.

Unfortunatelly, implementation of Toffoli gate requires many CNOT gates and single qubit rotation gates.

**My question: Is this implementation of Fredkin gate the most efficient one?**

Comment: *"My question: Is this implementation of Fredkin gate the most efficient one?"* -- Most efficient in terms of *what*?  Toffoli gates? Two-qubit gates? Sth. else? Have you e.g. checked out [Five two-bit quantum gates are sufficient to implement the quantum Fredkin gate](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.53.2855)?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch: I meant if is it possible to implement it with less gates (CNOTs and rotations) behind Toffoli gates.

Comment: I still don't understand.  What is your figure of merit?  E.g., you can get Fredkin with ***one*** Toffoli + 2 CNOTs.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch: It was answer to your question in terms of what. I will have a look at the paper you sent me. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, and I could not properly understand your question.  Are you trying to minimize the number of Toffoli gates, or the number of CNOTs and rotations in addition to a given number of Toffoli gates?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch: I am trying to minimize number of CNOTs and single qubit rotations. I started with three Toffoli and I was wondering whether it is possible to replace some Toffoli gate with simpler gates. Based on paper you send me, it seems possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on paper [Five Two-Bit Quantum Gates are Sucient to Implement the
Quantum Fredkin Gate](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/4774/7792a7b13028e47c9daa2259f77d264a27a8.pdf) provided by [Norbert Schuch](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/users/491/norbert-schuch), I realized that there is a more efficient implementation in terms of number of gates. Here is a result:

[image: Fredkin Gate]

Matrix of CNOT acting on $|q_1\rangle$ controlled by $|q_2\rangle$ is

\begin{equation}
CNOT_{2}=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

It can be verified that $(I \otimes CNOT_2)CCNOT(I \otimes CNOT_2)$ is matrix describing Fredkin gate.

Comment: What is noteworthy is that your question contains all the ingredients for this answer!  (Basically, once you understand that two CNOTs are a SWAP + a CNOT, you're there. All the rest is just putting a control on that.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch: I see, thanks. It is enough to control only the middle CNOT. In case $|q_0\rangle$ is  $|0\rangle$, left and right CNOT cancel each other as Toffoli is in this case just $I$. Only in case $|q_0\rangle$ is  $|1\rangle$ the middle CNOT works and all three gates implement swap gate.

Comment: Just note that design of Fredkin gate is an excercise no. 4.25 on pg. 182 in Nielsen and Chuang.